# Probability of travelling to a city (is my professor wrong?)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

I was given a homework question that reads:

A businesswoman in Philadelphia is preparing an itinerary for a visit to six major cities. The
distance traveled, and hence the cost of the trip, will depend on the order in which she plans
her route.

a) How many different itineraries (and trip costs) are possible?

b) If the businesswoman randomly selects one of the possible itineraries and Denver and San
Francisco are two of the cities that she plans to visit, what is the probability that she will
visit Denver before San Francisco

## My reasoning:

There are 6! possibilities. there are 3! ways of re-arranging the 3 cities that are neither denver nor san francisco.

We can see the following patterns

$D_1,S,\_,\_,\_,\_$

$D_1,D_2,S,\_,\_,\_$

$D_1,D_2,D_3,S,\_,\_$

$D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4,S,\_$

$D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4,D_5,S$

Where $D_i$ represents a possible position for denver.

There are thus 1 combinations in teh first case, 2 in the second...

Giving us a total of 3!$(1+2+3+4+5)=90$ possibilities for travelling to denver before san francisco.

90/6!=0.125

## My professor's answer

Denver - San Francisco - one of six cities) and (San Francisco - Denver - one of six
cities); hence, the probability that she will visit Denver before San Fransico is 0.5.

Who is correct, and if I am wrong, why is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: Completely unrelated, but: "professor" is spelt in the same way as "confessor", but with "pro" instead of "con".

Comment: It's got to be .5 by symmetry. Ask yourself how you argument would change if you interchanged San Francisco and Denver.

Comment: having been one myself, I say: professors are frequently wrong.

Comment: @Lubin I fixed the "proffessor" typo in the title before reading the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are $4$ cities that are neither Denver nor San Francisco. Your method works fine, but replacing $3!$ by $4!$ gives $4\cdot0.125=0.5$ as the correct solution, which is what your professor decided as well.